# Center a Widget on a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a streamBuilder but want to center a text Widget in it, I tried to use a center widget and it does nothing since the text Widget does not take the whole vertical space.

it looks like this:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Dtc>>(
      key: ValueKey(1),
      stream: bloc.dtcs,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot?.hasData ?? false) {
          // dtcs list is empty
          if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
            return Text(
              "My text to be centered"
            );
          } else {
            return Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 230.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        if (index >= snapshot.data.length) return null;
                        return AWidget();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        } else if (snapshot?.hasError ?? true) {
          return errorIcon;
        } else {
          return loadingIcon;
        }
      },
    );
```

is there a Widget that I am able to center the text Widget vertacly `Text("My text to be centered");`

Comment: Can you post the entire code for the widget? It might help understanding how the parent wraps your `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Row:

```
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("center text")
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: it is already centered horizontaly, I need this to center vertacly

Comment: Already tried this, the problem is that the row does not take up the whole space. I have mentioned this on the question

Comment: @key try setting `MainAxisSize` to max.

Comment: this does nothing, if the widget does not take up the whole space, i am already using the maximum space of the Wdiget. Expanded does not help either.

Answer (score -1):

The cleanest way to center a widget (in my opinion) is using the `Center` widget.

```
          Container(child: 
                   Center(child: Text("My text to be centered"),)
          ),
```

You can find more details about the `Center` widget here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html

Comment: as I mentioned this in the question, I already have tryed this

Comment: since the container has no size in that stage it wont work, I still gave it a try but it did not do the job.

Answer (score -1):

So what I had to do is to remove the `Expanded` which I put on the `ListView.builder` and wrap the whole `StreamBuilder` with it. and it worked.

something like this:

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Dtc>>(
...
```